# Use of copyrighted music on my dancing video app

Tags: copyright, music

I'm building a dancing video android app based on talent. I wanted to know if dancing videos which contain copyrighted music can actually be posted or if I should get music licensing from record labels first. In this case, how much money usually record labels require for new startups?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, you need a licence

They charge whatever you negotiate with them.